# reutilizar código html con función

Tags: html, jquery

tengo un formulario modal que lo uso en varias paginas. Quiero llamar  a una función y que me escriba el codigo del formulario modal.

```
function modalPrsp(){ //Función que me genera el mod

    document.body.innerHTML += " <div class='modal  ' id='modTarPrsp' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>"+
                    "<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>"+
                    "   <div class='modal-content'>"+
                            "<div class='modal-header' >"+

                            " <div class='form-group'>"+
                                 "<div class='col-xs-3   form-horizontal'>" +
                                    "<label class='checkbox-inline right-align '><input type='checkbox' id='chkOffTarPrsp'  value=''> Arhivada </label>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "<div class='col-xs-7   form-horizontal'>"+
                                    "<input type='text'  id='txtBusprsp'  class='form-control input-sm right-align' onfocus='keyEnter(btnModBusTarPrsp); return false;' >"+
                            "   </div>"+

                                "<div class='col-xs-1   form-horizontal'>"+
                                "<button  class='btn btn-primary btn-xs right-align' id='btnModBusTarPrsp'><span class=' glyphicon glyphicon-search '></span> </button>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+

                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='row clearfix  '>"+
                                "<div class='col-md-12 row-no-padding'   >"+
                                    "<div class='modal-body'>"+
                                        "<div  id='idHistoriasPrsp' height='150px' >"   +
                                            "<div id='cursor'>"+
                                                    "<table id='tblHisPrsp' class='hover cell-border row-border display compact '  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>"+
                                                        "<thead>"+
                                                            "<tr>"+
                                                                "<th>Id</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Historia</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Proyecto</th>"+
                                                            "</tr>"+
                                                        "</thead>"+
                                                    "</table>"+
                                                "</div>"+

                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div  id='idTareasPrsp'style='display:none;' > "+
                                            "<div class='panel panel-default'>"+
                                                "<div id='cursor'>"+
                                                    "<table id='tblTarPrsp' class='hover cell-border row-border display compact '  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>"+
                                                    "   <thead>"+
                                                            "<tr>"+
                                                                "<th>Id</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Tarea</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Descripci&oacute;n</th>"+
                                                            "</tr>"+
                                                        "</thead>"+
                                                    "</table>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                            "</div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='modal-footer'>"+
                                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs left-align' data-dismiss='modal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span> Cancelar </button>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>";

                $("#formPedido").on('submit', function(evt){
                    evt.preventDefault();  
                });
            }
```

De esta forma cuando llamo a la función, esta me escribe el modal, pero cuando vuelvo a llamarla, me escribe por duplicado y da error por que hay dos elementos con el mismo ID.

```js
function modalPrsp(){ //Función que me genera el mod

    document.body.innerHTML += " <div class='modal  ' id='modTarPrsp' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>"+
                    "<div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>"+
                    "   <div class='modal-content'>"+
                            "<div class='modal-header' >"+

                            " <div class='form-group'>"+
                                 "<div class='col-xs-3   form-horizontal'>" +
                                    "<label class='checkbox-inline right-align '><input type='checkbox' id='chkOffTarPrsp'  value=''> Arhivada </label>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "<div class='col-xs-7   form-horizontal'>"+
                                    "<input type='text'  id='txtBusprsp'  class='form-control input-sm right-align' onfocus='keyEnter(btnModBusTarPrsp); return false;' >"+
                            "   </div>"+

                                "<div class='col-xs-1   form-horizontal'>"+
                                "<button  class='btn btn-primary btn-xs right-align' id='btnModBusTarPrsp'><span class=' glyphicon glyphicon-search '></span> </button>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+

                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='row clearfix  '>"+
                                "<div class='col-md-12 row-no-padding'   >"+
                                    "<div class='modal-body'>"+
                                        "<div  id='idHistoriasPrsp' height='150px' >"   +
                                            "<div id='cursor'>"+
                                                    "<table id='tblHisPrsp' class='hover cell-border row-border display compact '  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>"+
                                                        "<thead>"+
                                                            "<tr>"+
                                                                "<th>Id</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Historia</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Proyecto</th>"+
                                                            "</tr>"+
                                                        "</thead>"+
                                                    "</table>"+
                                                "</div>"+

                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div  id='idTareasPrsp'style='display:none;' > "+
                                            "<div class='panel panel-default'>"+
                                                "<div id='cursor'>"+
                                                    "<table id='tblTarPrsp' class='hover cell-border row-border display compact '  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>"+
                                                    "   <thead>"+
                                                            "<tr>"+
                                                                "<th>Id</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Tarea</th>"+
                                                                "<th>Descripci&oacute;n</th>"+
                                                            "</tr>"+
                                                        "</thead>"+
                                                    "</table>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                            "</div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                "</div>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div class='modal-footer'>"+
                                "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs left-align' data-dismiss='modal'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-backward'></span> Cancelar </button>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>";

               
            }
            
            modalPrsp();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sería un poco mas simple imprimirlo en html oculto y mostrarlo cuando lo necesites no? qué cambia entre cada modal?

Comment: me queda la duda que frente al innerHTML += que presentas, en algun momento lo retiras? depronto es por ello que se duplica.

Comment: no tengo claro como imprimir en html, el modal no se ve hasta que yo no lo llamo con un boton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimínalo antes de llamarlo

```
$("#modTarPrsp").remove();
```